# how to sort files first before directories in 16.04 nautilus like in previous LTS version?

Tags: nautilus, file-sorting

Before, in 12.04&14.04, my download folder was nicely sorted by date : nautilus opened on top of the list with (newer)files first and then folders.

In 16.04 the directories are displayed first which i find annoying :

- order has changed
- i donwload files not directories, directories are the result of archives extractions and are not relevant for accessing to new downloads.
- i'm obliged to **manually** scroll or press end key to access the last downloaded file

There is an option in nautilus called "**sort-directories-first**", but when disabled it result in file&directories mixed together instead of files first.

What are the ways, if exists, to revert to the traditional sorting method "file first" ?

Comment: Well, if you just think about it, *sort-directories-first* can help to achieve the same thing. If you sort by date with sort-directories-first, it's the same with the order reversed. Only thing you may have to do is press the end key to get to the bottom of the directory once it's loaded.

Comment: thanks for you reply, i'll update the third point : i dont want manual action to check the latest download

Comment: maybe a global reverse option somewhere ?